# Feedback alert on iOS and android while capturing screenshot

Tags: android, ios, react-native

App shows an alert when users capture a screenshot on iOS and android which says **would you like to provide feedback?** I am having this issue on production. I want to remove this alert from my app. Please help.

[image]

Comment: how we can help you without code source ?

Comment: I don't believe this is a system alert, this is being presented by your code, so just stop presenting it.

Comment: This happens only when a screenshot is taken. So I am not sure about which part of the code I have to provide here. Also I have done a search for the displayed alert message throughout my project. Did not find any match.

Comment: I have experienced this issue on some of the apps on App Store as well. So I think this may not be related to my code.

Answer (score 0):

its because of TestFaisry: just do `TestFairy.disableFeedbackForm()`. in your ddelegate.